# I want to know if it is possible to call a java method, that calls a Servlet's method, from an HTML page

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am developing a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and I would like to know if it is possible to call a java method from an HTML input tag. To be more specific, I want this `<form method="post" action="/Ex2/Servlet1">` to be `<form method="post" action="/Ex2/Admin.java/CreateNewUser()">`. As you see, I want the input to call the function (`CreateNewUser()`) of class `Admin` and then this function to call `Servlet1`. Admin's function will be in the "middle"  of the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a Java method from HTML, HTML is interpreted in the browser and it only can send HTTP requests to a HTTP server, the requests are processed by servlets (apart from filters and other) so you need to have a servlet to process the request.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can call some Java method from your JSP file, adding scriptlet [scriptlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html) but is not a good practice.

I would recommend just use a proper endpoint in your action attribute, send the form to the controller, do all actions you need, create that user and redirect to any page you need.

**EDIT** 
KISS :)

To clarify....

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: Wow "KISS" really? 
I wonder the pace we are progressing in innovating closing messages. LOL

Comment: @XOR-Manik better if i add a link haha

Comment: Haha; it was sarcasm! @cralfaro but yes link clear the things out haha!